# STM32Cube: FreeRTOS 10.0.1 and CMSIS v2 generate warnings

Tags: stm32, freertos, cmsis, stm32cubemx

I'm using STM32Cube to generate an IAR EW 8.2 project with FreeRTOS 10.0.1 and CMSISv2 API's. When I clean up the project and build again, I get the following warnings

> *Warning[Pe177]: variable "hTask" was declared but never referenced*
>
> *Warning[Pe177]: variable "hTimer" was declared but never referenced*
>
> *Warning[Pe177]: variable "hEventGroup" was declared but never referenced*
>
> *Warning[Pe177]: variable "hSemaphore" was declared but never referenced*
>
> *Warning[Pe177]: variable "hQueue" was declared but never referenced*

I know that these warnings should not affect my code but I would be interested if this warnings are always there or if they depend on my settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are warnings being generated by IAR's compiler.  They'll go away after those variables are used.  If they aren't used. . . get rid of them and the warnings will also go away ;-)  Dead code is never a good thing to keep around!  Specifically, you should really consider treating warnings more like errors, since it will force a cleaner code base.

If you *really* want to supress warnings, you can mask individual warnings in IAR:
1.  Select Project-->Options-->Compiler tab
2.  Select Suppress these diagnostics  and specify your desired warning
3. Click OK.

Comment: _get rid of them_ ... Thats my problem. They are generated by the STM32Cube and I can't get rid of them ;)

Comment: I think using Cube for anything more than a glorified example creator is the 1st problem ;-)  Granted, I haven't had great experience with it (or STM HAL) over the years. . . and I wish STM would bring back the Standard Peripheral Library. . .

Comment: Ok, understood :D